# Filter on ID values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Im experiencing an issue when filtering a field using a value of IDs, not sure how that can happen, here's the mapping and an example.

As can be seen after adding a new user, with the `primary_user` set to `AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB` it will not be found using `filter` unless `keyword` is used in the filter request.
This only happens with values of IDs.
What's the root cause for this behavior?

```
   GET users/_mapping/

    Response:
    {
     ...
     ...
     "primary_user": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
    }
------
    POST users/user
    {
      "primary_user": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
    }

    Response:
    {
      "_index": "users",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": "AWIaOFgQmedTIIkbtGPG",
      "_version": 1,
      "result": "created",
      "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "created": true
    }
------
    GET users/user/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "primary_user": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    Response:
    {
      "took": 0,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
      }
}
------
    GET users/user/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "primary_user.keyword": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    Response:
    {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "AWIaOFgQmedTIIkbtGPG",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "primary_user": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `primary_user` has a text datatype, as written in your mappings:

```
 "primary_user": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
```

So or you change the field to query against:

```
GET users/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "primary_user.keyword": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or change from term to match query:

```
GET users/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "primary_user": "AWBFyulclsp0PJbvPiuB"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lupanoide, how can I set primary_user to be keyword? (when I created it's template, i set it to keyword) Should it be text instead? what makes sense here?

Comment: For your use case is better keyword, text datatype has no sense. text datatype provides a fulltext search so the content of your field is subvided on tokens and you could make operations on them to retrieve not only the literal word. E.g. if you have a text datatype and you use a stemmer as token filter and in the content you have the words taken and took, they will be retrieved both if you search for take. Keyword datatype implements a literal search that is better for alphanumeric codes

Comment: You can't change the mapping of an index when it already exists, except when you create new standalone fields or fields to Objects -multifield. If you want to replace a object field with text and keyword fields with a keyword datatype, you need to create new mapping and reindex your docs